# Website Structure with controller= in URL?

Tags: php, html, mysql

First off I apologize if the answer to this question is elsewhere. I have tried every word combination I could think of on search engines with no luck. However, I am confident I could explain my question to a human and they will know what I am looking for!

The question:

What is a website called that uses category, product, or user IDs in the url to construct the page? I have found the name before, I think it was a 3 part name often abbreviated, but for the life if me I can't remember what it was called! Driving me crazy.

Example:

Edit: https://www.greenjusticecomics.com/index.php?id_product=115&controller=product

This would bring up whatever category 10 is and the 145th product on the site. I have watched youtube videos and have seen a few books on this I wanted to buy, but it has been a while and without the name of the practice I can't relocate them!

Thanks in advanced for helping me find this answer! You will have cured my insanity! Ha.

Comment: What you have there (kinda) is a querystring. Maybe you're thinking of REST?

Comment: Do you think of an (REST) Api? In that case it would be one that gets the needed parameters over GET Requests.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, apologize if it's off topic. It was the closest relation I could make to a concept I can't name. That being said, I don't believe it has to do with any API. It is a method that uses one index.php file to pilot the whole website, with possibly secondaries for headers, footers, or any other consistent designs. Here is an example of the sites structure (my current website based on PrestaShop: www.greenjusticecomics.com). It is my goal to rewrite the entire site and move away from PrestaShop. I want full control and understanding over every element and its structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This style website uses a MVC or Model View Controller. It took me some time to find it, but thank you for the comments that helped lead this horse to water (the answer). Here is a wiki link to what exactly an MVC is as well as a tutorial for those future seekers that may come across my question. I won't want anyone else to get negative reputation.

Wiki:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Tutorial:
https://r.je/views-are-not-templates.html

Hope this helps others in the future!